# Excel OFFSET and FILTER combo formula error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering why I cannot use OFFSET with FILTER as it returns a #VALUE error. I when I ran the portion of the formula with OFFSET with a parameter, how come it returns as True or False rather than returning a list of numbers that I need. Any suggestions with directing my equation will help!

I had a specific range of an array to filter out, but as soon as the filtering is viable then using OFFSET on the entire array to look for adjacent non-blank values is next.

```
=FILTER( INDIRECT($A$6&"!$B$5:$Q$34") , 
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$C$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$C:$C" )) - 5 ) >= $A$9) *
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$C$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$C:$C" )) - 5 ) <= $A$10) * 
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$D$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$D:$D" )) - 5 ) >= $A$13) * 
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$D$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$D:$D" )) - 5 ) <= $A$14) * 
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$I$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$I:$I" )) - 5 ) >= $A$17) * 
( OFFSET( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$I$5" ), 0, 0, COUNTA( INDIRECT( $A$6&"!$I:$I" )) - 5 ) <= $A$18), 
 "None")
```

Comment: The range you are filtering, i.e. `B5:Q34`, comprises 30 rows. Have you ensured that each of the `OFFSET` ranges also comprises 30 rows? If any of them do not, you will receive a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: I have not, so if I were to set the range to the OFFSET would that also work? Or does FILTER need a specific range to work? The end product was intended to be a dynamic range that can filter out any range of array with given constraints at specific columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosWoolley stated, the number of rows is probably not equal. To ensure all the same number of rows you should do the `COUNTA` all on the same column.  And you can leverage LET to do that once:

```
=LET(
    rw, COUNTA(INDIRECT($A$6&"!B:B")),
    FILTER(INDIRECT($A$6&"!B5:Q" & rw),
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!C5:C" & rw) >= $A$9) *
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!C5:C" & rw) <= $A$10) *
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!D5:D" & rw) >= $A$13) *
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!D5:D" & rw) <= $A$14) *
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!I5:I" & rw) >= $A$17) *
          (INDIRECT($A$6&"!I5:I" & rw) <= $A$18),
          "NONE"))
```